# MySQL: How to select a different query based on a given value?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible select via SQL which query gets executed? I need to integrate this logic into SQL as there is not way via the application itself.

The following query does the trick but in it always executes both queries. Is there a way to do this without executing both all the time?

```
SELECT 
  time_sec, 
  SUM(RIX), 
  value 
FROM (
  -- categories
  SELECT 
    time_sec,
    RIX,
    value
  FROM
    cat
  WHERE $dimension IN (0,1)

  UNION ALL

  -- search
  SELECT 
    time_sec,
    RIX,
    value
  FROM
    search
  WHERE $dimension IN (0,2)  
) t
GROUP by time_sec, value
```

How to faster select between two queries based on $dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  It would be faster to use a Stored Procedure so you can use `IF` statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
BEGIN
    IF ( EXISTS(SELECT ...) )   -- or any other true/false test
    THEN
        SELECT ...
    ELSE
        SELECT ...
    END IF
END
```

Plan B: Do both, then throw away one:

```
SELECT a,b,c
    FROM (
        ( SELECT 1 AS option, a,b,c FROM ... )
        UNION ALL
        ( SELECT 2 AS option, a,b,c FROM ... )
         ) AS x
    WHERE option = ...;   -- Here is where you pick which one
```

Limitation for plan B:  The columns of the 2 SELECTs must match.